# Angular UI-Bootstrap popover draggable

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

I am using [Angular UI-Bootstrap popover](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/popover) and want to make it draggable using [jQuery-UI draggable](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/). It all works as supposed to, but I am having an issue with UI-Bootstrap repositioning. If I hover on an element that has tooltip or open another popup, then UI-Bootstrap recalculates the popup placement and puts it to its initial placement. But I would like it to stay where it was dragged. Is there any workaround on this?

My code samples

HTML

```
<button type="button" data-uib-tooltip="Toggle tooltip" data-tooltip-placement="bottom auto" data-tooltip-append-to-body="true" data-tooltip-class="hidden-xs" data-uib-popover-template="'popover.tpl.html'" data-popover-append-to-body="false" data-popover-placement="auto left" data-popover-class="popover-default popover-draggable" data-ng-click="vm.makeDraggable()">
    Toggle popover
</button>
```

JS

```
vm.makeDraggable = function() {
    $('.popover-draggable').draggable();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You maybe need to store the last position of the popover. You can use the **event drag** to get the current position.

```
$( ".popover-draggable" ).draggable({
   drag: function( event, ui ) {
    //get position with ui.position
   }
});
```

Comment: I could get the position, but ui-bootstrap resets it and if I choose to reset it after the reset, then there would be unwanted flickering

Comment: Indeed it's a Bootstrap issue. Bootstrap doesn't allow to give custom position to the popover. A solution maybe be to create a custom popover without Bootstrap.